# como solucionar un error al calcular los percentiles agrupados en r

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una base de datos con puntajes a la cual necesito crear una nueva columna con percentiles agrupados por región, es decir que a cada ID, le indique el percentil en el que está según su región, intenté el siguiente comando

```
ptje2021 <- ptje2021 %>%
  group_by(ptje2021$codido_reg_egreso)%>%
  mutate(percent_TOTAL = cut(TOTAL,
                             unique(
                               quantile(TOTAL,
                                        probs = seq(0, 1, 1/100), 
                                        na.rm = TRUE)),
                             include.lowest = TRUE),
         percent_TOTAL = as.numeric(percent_TOTAL))
```

cuando corre,  aparecen percentiles mayores a 100 y no a todos les indica su percentil correspondiente. ¿cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que dejes un data frame como ejemplo.

Pero como no dejaste crearé un data frame que sirva como ejemplo.

```
set.seed(2020)
df<-data.frame(region=sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),1000,T),
           ID=sample(1:10000,1000,F),
           puntaje=sample(1:10000,1000,T))
```

El data frame sería el siguiente:

```
head(df)
  region   ID puntaje
1      D 8641     841
2      D 6973     395
3      F 6327    8602
4      A 3375    2495
5      A 7796    1180
6      D 7787    8970
```

Ahora, tu código es casi el indicado, pero no deberías de considerar la función `unique()`.

El código sería.

```
df %>% group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(percentil=as.numeric(cut(puntaje, 
                   breaks = quantile(puntaje, 
                   probs = seq(0,1, length.out=101)),
                   right = T, include.lowest = T)))
```

El resultado será el siguiente:

```
head(df)

  region    ID puntaje percentil
  <chr>  <int>   <int>     <dbl>
1 D       8641     841         9
2 D       6973     395         3
3 F       6327    8602        86
4 A       3375    2495        27
5 A       7796    1180        12
6 D       7787    8970        91
```